# Elasticsearch query for multiple terms

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I am trying to create a search query that allows to search by name and type.
I have indexed the values, and my record in Elasticsearch look like this:

```
{
  _index: "assets",
  _type: "asset",
  _id: "eAOEN28BcFmQazI-nngR",
  _score: 1,
  _source: {
    name: "test.png",
    mediaType: "IMAGE",
    meta: {
      content-type: "image/png",
      width: 3348,
      height: 1890,
    },
    createdAt: "2019-12-24T10:47:15.727Z",
    updatedAt: "2019-12-24T10:47:15.727Z",
  }
}
```

so how would I create for example, a query that finds all assets that have the name "test' and are images?

I tried multi_mach query but that did not return the correct results:

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":      "*test* IMAGE",
      "type":       "cross_fields",
      "fields":     [ "name", "mediaType" ],
      "operator":   "and" 
    }
  }
}
```

The query above returns 0 results, and if I change the operator to "or" it returns all this assets of type IMAGE.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. TIA!

**EDIT: Added Mapping**
Below is the mapping:

```
{
    "assets": {
        "aliases": {},
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "__v": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "createdAt": {
                    "type": "date"
                },
                "deleted": {
                    "type": "date"
                },
                "mediaType": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "meta": {
                    "properties": {
                        "content-type": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "width": {
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "height": {
                          "type": "long"
                      }
                    }
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "originalName": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "updatedAt": {
                    "type": "date"
                }
            }
        },
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "creation_date": "1575884312237",
                "number_of_shards": "1",
                "number_of_replicas": "1",
                "uuid": "nSiAoIIwQJqXQRTyqw9CSA",
                "version": {
                    "created": "7030099"
                },
                "provided_name": "assets"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your index mapping and settings?

Comment: @tomslabbaert I have updated my question to include the mapping and settings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are unnecessary using the wildcard expression for this simple query.

### First, change your analyzer on `name` field.

You need to create a custom analyzer which replaces `.` with `space` as default standard analyzer doesn't do that, so that you when searching for `test` you get `test.png` as there will be both `test` and `png` in the inverted index. **The main benefit of doing this is to avoid the regex queries which are very costly**.

Updated mapping with custom analyzer which would do the work for you. Just update your mapping and re-index again all the doc.

```
{
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "__v": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "createdAt": {
                "type": "date"
            },
            "deleted": {
                "type": "date"
            },
            "mediaType": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "meta": {
                "properties": {
                    "content-type": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "width": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "height": {
                        "type": "long"
                    }
                }
            },
            "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer" : "my_analyzer"
            },
            "originalName": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "updatedAt": {
                "type": "date"
            }
        }
    },
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "my_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "char_filter": [
                        "replace_dots"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "char_filter": {
                "replace_dots": {
                    "type": "mapping",
                    "mappings": [
                        ". => \\u0020"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "index": {
            "number_of_shards": "1",
            "number_of_replicas": "1"
        }
    }
}
```

### Second, you should change your query to bool query as below:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "name": "test"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "mediaType.keyword": "IMAGE"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Which is using must with 2 match queries means, that it would return docs only when there is a match in all the clauses of must query.

I already tested my solution by creating the index, inserting a few sample docs and query them, let me know if you need any help.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and answer! This works.

Comment: @Ronnyvdb happy to know this

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried with **best_fields** ?

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":      "Will Smith",
      "type":       "best_fields",
      "fields":     [ "name", "mediaType" ],
      "operator":   "and" 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but still returns 0 results